# Get keys of Dictionary in array in original order

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary

```
let dict = [
    "Joe":"D.",
    "Ben":"K.",
    "Kyle":"R.",
    "Matt":"L."
]
```

If I wanted an array of the keys of this dictionary I do:

```
let keys = Array(dict.keys)
```

But this prints in a seemingly random order:

```
["Ben", "Joe", "Matt", "Kyle"]
```

Is there a way to get an array of keys that with the same order as the origin dictionary?

i.e.

```
["Joe", "Ben", "Kyle", "Matt"]
```

Comment: Dictionaries don't have any order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries don't have order. When we add new element to dictionary we don't now the order. You can use **Array of Tuple**

```
        let array = [("Joe", "D."), ("Ben", "K."), ("Kyle", "R.")]
        print(array)
//        [("Joe", "D."), ("Ben", "K."), ("Kyle", "R.")]
        let keys = array.map { $0.0 }
        print(keys)
//        ["Joe", "Ben", "Kyle"]
```

Comment: Irfan is right dictionary are not mean't to retain their order, They work on principal of Key-Value encoding. You will have to use array.